# set default value in select2 dropdown in yii2

Tags: yii2, jquery-select2

I have a kartik select2 dependent dropdown in yii2 and i want to select a value as a default selected value.

```
<?=$form->field($EmployeeLeaveModel, 'EmployeeID')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                        'data' => $Employee,
                        'language' => 'en',
                        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Employee  ...'],
                        'pluginOptions' => [
                                'allowClear' => true
                             ],
                ]);
        ?>
```

How do i get a default value as selected in the dropdown?

Comment: `$EmployeeLeaveModel->EmployeeID = value;`

Comment: where do i have to add this?

Comment: Before using model in select2.

Comment: Probably in controller is good or add directly in view before your field.

Comment: Thanks i achieved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller

```
$EmployeeLeaveModel->EmployeeID = value;
```

**OR**

In view

```
$EmployeeLeaveModel->EmployeeID = value;

<?= $form->field($EmployeeLeaveModel, 'EmployeeID')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
     'data' => $Employee,
     'language' => 'en',
     'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Employee,...'],   
]) ?>
```